# Confusion about U(1) bundle on a torus

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I have some confusions about Chern number of U(1) bundle on a torus. I list my understanding below and please help me to figure out the problem.

1. A one-form $A$ can be defined over the whole torus.
2. To define a connection one-form for this bundle, we need a Lie-algebra valued one-form on the torus. So I can simply define this form by adding an $i$ to $A$  as $iA$.
3. So the Lie-algebra valued local curvature two-form is $F = diA + iA \wedge iA = idA$
4. If there is no continuous section can be found. Both $iA$ and $F$ can only be well defined on local charts. In the overlapping parts ${U_i} \cap {U_j}$ the transition function is  ${t_{ij}}(p) = \exp [i\Lambda (p)]$. So we have the transition  $iA \to iA +i d\Lambda (p)$ and $F \to t_{ij}^{ - 1}Ft_{ij}^{ - 1} = F$ and the Chern number is found as
   $\int_T {\frac{i}{{2\pi }}trF = } \int_T {\frac{i}{{2\pi }}F}  \in Z$

So $F$ is exactly $idA$ everywhere? is this right ?

If so,  by directly appling stokes theorem
$\int_T {F =  - i} \int_T {dA = } \int_{\partial T} {A = 0} $
I found the Chern number must be 0?  What is wrong here? Please help.